# Hangout chat doesn't show my bot as user

Tags: google-hangouts

I have followed the instructions as per the https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/bots-develop?authuser=1

1. Created my agent - named as "phoebieagent".
2. Defined intents and entities.
3. Fulfilled by webhook and running a flask python API on https.
4. Published by bot as hangouts chat. Specified bot url to be the one
   defined in step 3.

Bot status shows - "live" but in my hangouts I can't see my bot user.

Please suggest trouble shooting steps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it. Chat was disabled in google admin console.